# Partially using Vue with nginx

Tags: django, vue.js, nginx

I'm trying to use both vue.js and Django with nginx. The issue is, that it still redirect my /subscriptions/ url to Django. Removing the '/' rule would make it work though. Is there a way to "skip" Django when the url matches 'custom'?

Basically, I would like to specify which links would be used with vue, and the rest with Django.

```
location = /custom/ {
    root /home/django/project/frontend/dist;
    index /index.html;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/project/project.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. For some reason it needs 2 slashes in the root.

```
root /home/django/tradeium/frontend/dist//;
index index.html;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/project/project.sock;
}

location = /custom/ {

    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will serve the files inside `/home/django/project/frontend/dist/` if the path of the request starts with '/custom/'

```
location /custom/ {
    root /home/django/project/frontend/dist/;
    index /index.html;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/project/project.sock;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns a django 404 error and "Request URL: domain_com/index.html

Comment: What's the exact URL you are trying to access?

Comment: domain.com/custom/

Comment: Can you update your question with the whole nginx config, contents of the nginx access.log, and error.log files

Comment: It's just the default stuff. The logs show no error, access.log has a 404 call. 
Removing the / rule makes vue work.  If I would to add a return 500; to /custom/ it will return the 500 error. But it not, it just redirects the request to Django.

Comment: I see that the issue is proxy_pass, I have to disable it somehow for /custom/

Comment: Were you able to solve it? If not I'll proceed with more comments.

Comment: Yes I did in the comment below.